# KerasClassifier - Sci-Kit learn pipeline [Attribute Error]

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I am using Sci-kit learn's pipeline with a KerasClassfier at the end. The classifier would load in the trained model for prediction. But after adding the classifier to the pipeline (3 components in total), I received an error AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'model' after calling pipeline.predict_proba. I think it expects me to fit it but I am importing a trained model. I can't find anything relevant online. Your kind help is greatly appreciated. The following is relevant part of my code:

```
def buildEngModelByLoading():
  # load json and create model
  json_file = open('saved_model/cnnModel.json', 'r')
  loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
  json_file.close()
  loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
  # load weights into new model
  loaded_model.load_weights("saved_model/cnnModel.h5")
  print("Loaded classifier model")
  return loaded_model

engSklearnCnn = KerasClassifier(build_fn=buildEngModelByLoading, epochs=20, batch_size=batchSize, verbose=1)
#Append classfier to one pipeline
pipeline.steps.insert(2,['classifier',engSklearnCnn])`
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you forgot to use `compile` method first before `predict` function.

```
buildEngModelByLoading().compile(optimizer = 'classifier_optimizer', loss = 'loss_function', metrics = 'metrics')
```

Then just replace `classifier_optimizer`, `loss_function`, `metrics` with your parameters used.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your suggestion and the error says KerasClassifier has no attribute compile. I guess the wrapper makes it no longer the native Keras model. So I tried calling compile within the build function on loaded_model after loading the weights, then it gives the same error of not having attribute 'model'

Comment: @soulless, I updated my answer.You should use `compile` method for the imported model

Comment: Do u mean I should have it like this? Doesn't seem to to work 
engSklearnCnn = KerasClassifier(build_fn=buildEngModelByLoading().compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']), epochs=20, batch_size=batchSize, verbose=1)

Comment: I am supposed to call predict with pipeline.predict_proba after wrapping the keras model with the KerasClassifier wrapper

Comment: Yes, you have to use compile method before creating kerasclassifier

Comment: I tried putting that within the build function before returning the model, same error..